# Parse.com - Parse PHP SDK - How can I query data by pointer field?

Tags: php, pointers, parse-platform

I have two objects Puzzle and the PuzzleAnswer. 
In PuzzleAnswer I have field "`puzzle Pointer<Puzzle>`" which equal to field "objectId" in Puzzle.
How can I query answers by pointer field "puzzle"?
This code work well with all field except "puzzle".

```
$query = new ParseQuery("PuzzleAnswer");
$query->equalTo("Puzzle", "kBT3M6YpvY");
$result = $query->find();

print "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

result:

```
array(0) {
```

}

Thank.

Comment: i haven't used Parse but, as i checked documentation now, yout equalTo method receives ParseObject so can you try this;

    $puzzle = new OarseObject('kBT3M6YpvY');
    $query->equalTo('Puzzle', $puzzle);

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked out, but it didn't help.
The fact that it works for other fields, the problem is only with the field puzzle which is "Pointer"

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for a pointer field with a string. It requires you to search with a Parse Object.

Either create a query for the pointer fields object:

$puzzle = new ParseQuery('Puzzle');

$puzzle->equalTo('objectId', $puzzleId);

$first = $puzzle->first();

Or by bypassing this and passing it an object we create

$query->equalTo("Puzzle", ['__type' => "Pointer", 'className'=> "Puzzle", 
'objectId' => $id]);

$result = $query->find();